# Using frequency-compensated resistive divider as digital level-shifter

Tags: voltage-divider, level-shifting, compensation

We have all seen the "frequency-compensated resistive divider" circuit in, for example, 10X oscilloscope probes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff3aQA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Has anyone tried such a circuit as a unidirectional digital level-shifter?

I am working on some asynchronous 5-volt legacy memory systems, with the aim of replacing static asynchronous DRAM and SRAM modules with new modules using DDR SDRAM chips. This requires a fast clock for the SDRAM and to synchronize the incoming asynchronous control signals to the fast clock domain. The timing for this kind of system must be very tight. Our designs currently use buffers to level-shift the incoming 5V control signals to 3.3V, where they are input into an FPGA, which synchronizes them to the SDRAM clock domain and issues the proper SDRAM commands to perform the access requested.

I am desiring to shave off another 3 nanoseconds or so from the worst-case timing path by replacing some level-shifting buffers with a resistive divider circuit like I show above, but intentionally overcompensated and with Schottky clamps:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgVHEq.png)</sup>

Has anyone applied this technique before? What potential "gotchas" exist? I am aware of the various level-shifting FET switches, but I don't feel that they justify their (fairly high) cost if this circuit is workable.

Comment: Watch out for the capacitance of those diodes.

Comment: I second Brian’s comment. The total capacitive loading of your proposed discrete circuits is going to slow up your edge by more than 3 ns. Stick with fast level shifters.